# IE makes two indents instead of one

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have some JS code that implements a typewriter effect. However, if everything works fine on google chrome, then in IE why additional indents appear.

In the console in chrome there are 2 indents in ie 3, why is it always one more, is this a bug?

```js
let textBox = document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1'),
    text    = textBox.innerText,
    newHTML = '';

for(i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    newHTML += '<span>'+text[i]+'</span>';
}
textBox.innerHTML = newHTML;

let spans   = textBox.querySelectorAll('span'),
    count   = 0,
    timeout = 0;

function typing_text(){
    spans[count].classList.add('visible');
    if(spans[count].innerText == '\n' || spans[count].innerHTML == '\n'){
        timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000));
        spans[count-1].classList.add('cursor');
    
    }else{
        timeout = 150;
    }

    if (count < text.length - 1){
        setTimeout(function() {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function (e) {
                e.classList.remove('cursor'); 
             }); 
            count ++;
            typing_text();
        }, timeout);
    }
}

typing_text();
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 290px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
/* Animation */
.index-title-main h1 span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.index-title-main h1 span.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
.index-title-main h1 span.cursor {
    background: #34DEB4;
    width: 2px;
    animation: blinking 0.5s step-start infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-title-main"><h1>Text 1 <br>Text 2, <br>Text 3</h1></div>
```

Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

Internet Explorer 11:

[image: Internet Explorer 11]

Comment: Do you _really_ need to support IE11? That thing is dead.

Comment: Everything else is compatible with it. I do not want such a trifle to work crookedly there.

Comment: My guess would be that it probably handles line breaks differently (in that you are getting `\r\n` instead of a single `\n` in other browsers), and since the text gets split character by character and each one wrapped in a span, you likely have spans containing only `\r` in between there now … and in combination with `white-space: pre`, that is causing empfy lines.

Comment: Your snippet works the same on Chrome and IE11 - but neither looks like the images you have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in favor of CBroe's comment. It gets `\r\n` in IE which makes the issue. If you replace `\r\n` with `\n`, then it can work well in IE and Chrome.

You can use the following method to replace `\r\n` with `\n`:

```
text = text.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, "\n");
```

Result in IE 11:

[image]